# Activity Stack is getting empty

Tags: android, android-activity

I am opening a new intent above another. I am able to go back from second activity to first when I minimise the app by pressing the home button, the activity stack is getting empty. When I re-open the app and try to go back, it minimise the app.
How can I stop the activity stack from getting empty?

This is how I open new activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SiteActivity.this, WebviewActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("url", s[s.length - 1]); //Optional parameters
    myIntent.putExtra("win", false);
    SiteActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Something same was happened with me last month, the reason I found is that I was not calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` on my `onCreate();` method. Track the logcat response.